# Cosine similarity in python3

Tags: python-3.x

I have two lists

I have used word to vector and cosine similarity to find the similar words based on cosine value between two vectors.

I have already defined word to vector function and cosine similarities so I did not mention that here.

```
tar1 = ['apple','fruit', 'vegetable','school']
tar2 = ['fruit', 'apple', 'school','vegetable']

i=0
j=0
for i in range (len(tar1)):
    vect1 = text_to_vector(tar1[i].strip().lower())

    for j in range(len(keyword)):
        vect2 = text_to_vector(tar2[j].strip().lower())
        cosine = get_cosine(vect1, vect2)
        j = j+1
i = i+1
```

In the nested loop I want to pick out the string which has maximum cosine similarity value after the inner loops runs.

Eg:
First item in tar1 is 'apple'
which has high cosine similarity of 'apple' in tar2. so based on high cosine similarity. it has to pick out the word

I am looking for the output like below.

o/p = ['apple','fruit', 'vegetable','school']

Comment: What does `get_cosine()` function return? Numeric values? What's the range? 0 to 1? Also `tar1` and `tar2` have the same words in different order. Looks like your code just sorts `tar2` according to `tar1`. Can you provide more useful/general example?

Comment: The cosine function gives the cosine similarity value of two strings. for eg: cosine similarity of of apple and apple is 1. the function of get_cosine i did not add it here.I just want to compare the strings from tar1 in tar2 and append it in new list based on the the highest matching cosine function value

Comment: Provide another example of `tar1` and `tar2` please. Can they have different sets of words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible implementation to get what you want (with comments):

```
def text_to_vector(text):
    return text


def get_cosine(x, y):
    return 1 if x == y else 0


tar1 = ['apple', 'fruit', 'vegetable', 'school']
tar2 = ['fruit', 'apple', 'school', 'vegetable']

result = list()
# iterate over words in tar1
for dummy_idx_1, vector_1 in enumerate(text_to_vector(word) for word in tar1):
    # keep track of the maximum cosine and most similar word
    max_cosine, best_word = -1, None
    # iterate over words in tar2 for every word in tar1
    for idx_2, vector_2 in enumerate(text_to_vector(word) for word in tar2):
        # compute cosine
        cosine = get_cosine(vector_1, vector_2)
        # check if current word from tar2 is the most similar to the word from tar1
        if cosine > max_cosine:
            max_cosine, best_word = cosine, tar2[idx_2]
    # remember result for every word from tar1
    result.append(best_word)

print(result)
```

Output is:

```
['apple', 'fruit', 'vegetable', 'school']
```